# need to embed the url inside hyperlink in mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button on an ASP.NET webpage. When the button is clicked an email is sent to users. Inside the body of the mail message I have the following URL; `https://synerg.abc.com/abctool/Login.aspx`.

Instead of having the full link visible, I just want to show a "Click Here" hyperlink which will take the user to the above URL when clicked. The URL should then be redirected to `https://synerg.abc.com/documenttrackingtool/Login.aspx`

```
protected void Uab_abc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClnt;
    MailMessage objMail;

    // Prepare Email  
    // Load Email Template from HTML File. 

    // Send Email
    // Create new Mail Object
    objMail = new MailMessage(); // Create new Mail Object
    objMail.From = new MailAddress("tracking@abc.com");

    //test mailers
    objMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
    objMail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
    objMail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));

    objMail.Subject = "abc Delivery HNC";
    string EMailBody = @"  
        <table>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Dear L2 / L3 Heads,
                </td>
            <br/>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td>Please find below pending abc Status.  Request delivery leaders to closely track UBR and ensure invoiced at the earliest.  
                </td>
            <br/>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td>Recovery Status Date : 13th November 2019
                </td>  
            </tr>    
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                  <img src=""cid:InlineImageID"" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>You can also access this report using below link / Path
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>Link : https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>User Id : your Myabc User id or SAP code
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>PWD : your Myabc password.
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>Navigate to path :  DTT  Dashboard -> abc -> abc Delivery -> L1 / L2 files.
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <br/>
            <tr>  
                <td>Regards,
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td>abc Team.
                </td> 
            </tr></table>  
          ";

    // Now we'll create two email views: HTML and plain text
    // First, create HTML view
    AlternateView HTMLEmail = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EMailBody,
            null, "text/html");
    // Create plain text view for those visitors who prefer text only messages
    AlternateView PlainTextEmail = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EMailBody, null, "text/plain");

    // We'll need LinkedResource class to place an image to HTML email
    LinkedResource MyImage = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/images/abc_Delivery_L2_abcmail.png"));
    // Set ContentId property. Value of ContentId property must be the same as
    // the src attribute of image tag in email body. In this case it is 
    // <img src="cid:InlineImageID" />
    MyImage.ContentId = "InlineImageID";

    // Add this linked resource to HTML view
    HTMLEmail.LinkedResources.Add(MyImage);

    // Add plain text and HTML views to an email
    objMail.AlternateViews.Add(HTMLEmail);
    objMail.AlternateViews.Add(PlainTextEmail);

    // Open SMTP Connection to Mail Server and send email.
    smtpClnt = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClnt.Host = "10.99.134.21";
    smtpClnt.Port = Convert.ToInt16("25");
    smtpClnt.EnableSsl = false;
    smtpClnt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    smtpClnt.Send(objMail);

    smtpClnt.Dispose(); // Close the SMTP Mail server connection.
    objMail.Dispose(); // Clear the mail object

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `<a>` tag? Used like: `<a href="URL">Click Here To Login</a>`

Comment: yes exactly it should just display as click here in mail body , when clicked on it , it should redirect to the required url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this:

```
<tr>  
    <td>Link : https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx
    </td> 
</tr>
```

To this:

```
<tr>  
    <td><a href="https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx">click here</a>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

And this:

```
<tr>  
    <td>Recovery Status Date : 13th November 2019
    </td>  
</tr>
```

To this:

```
<tr>  
    <td>Recovery Status Date : #dateToReplace
    </td>  
</tr>
```

Also:

```
EMailBody = EMailBody.Replace("#dateToReplace", DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy"));

// Now we'll create two email views: HTML and plain text
// First, create HTML view
AlternateView HTMLEmail = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EMailBody,
        null, "text/html");
```

Comment: thanks, and also if you see in the code , i have mentioned a date inside the mail body as 13th November 2019 , which is manually changed everyday , can we make it in such a way that whenever the button is clicked it should display current date, without changing it every day

Comment: actually getting a build error when trying to replace the line saying invalid expression term '<'

Comment: Please add the information about the date at the question too.

Comment: Please update the question with the new code. It helps me to help you :)

Comment: replaced these lines in the code <tr>  
    <td><a href="https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx">click here</a>
    </td> 
</tr> getting build errors am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<td>Link : https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx</td>
```

with

```
<td>Link : <a href='https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx'>Login</a></td>
```

Replace *Login* with the text you want to display, e.g., *click here*

---

**Edit**:
Also
Replace

```
<td>Recovery Status Date : 13th November 2019</td>
```

with

```
<td>Recovery Status Date : [RECOVERYDATE]</td>
```

Also include

```
EMailBody = EMailBody.Replace("[RECOVERYDATE]", DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy"));
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings for more details about formatting dates.

Comment: thanks, and also if you see in the code , i have mentioned a date inside the mail body as 13th November 2019 , which is manually changed everyday , can we make it in such a way that whenever the button is clicked it should display current date, without changing it every day

Comment: actually getting a build error when trying to replace the line the error is invalid expression term '<'

Comment: replaced <td>Link : https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx</td>  with <td>Link : <a href="https://synerg.abc.com/tool/Login.aspx">Login</a></td> but getting build errors as invalid expression term '<' am i missing anything

Comment: Use ' instead of "

Comment: EMailBody = EMailBody.Replace("#dateToReplace", DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy")); where i should add this line in the code can you help

Comment: After  `string EMailBody ` but keep in mind that my solution uses the word RECOVERYDATE . You are mixing my solution with the one from @Lutti Coelho